Did this issue fixed for Binary WebSocketV2 (Updating Apache Ignite WebSession attributes)
Updating attributes in Ignite WebSessionFilter is fixed as per the link, but same fix is not applied for WebSocketV2.java.
Is this not impacted??
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-2594

This question is probably better addressed to the Ignite Developer mailing list. Also, this was resolved in Ignite 1.6 (around eight years ago) and is unlikely to still be relevant.
